# Ajax rss feed - openweathermap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, rss

so I get the feed after choosing an option but its not "refreshing as new news come".
I have the same problem with openweather.
Is the "GET" my problem or browser or something else? I guess everything is cached but it should not.
Should it be POST and not GET how sould I change that with the current code?
thanks!

```
<script>

nocache = "&nocache" + Math.random()* 1000000
url = "$q"
out = "";


function showRSS(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str+nocache,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>

<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_GET["q"];

//find out which feed was selected
if($q=="Baden-Württemberg") {
  $xml=("https://verkehrsmeldungen.polizei-bw.de/TicRss.ashx?region=BW");
} elseif($q=="Bayern") {
  $xml=("http://www.br.de/verkehr-static/verkehrsmeldungen-rss.xml");
}

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p ><a href='" . $channel_link
  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<p ><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}

    ?>
```

Comment: so you want it to be refreshing after the first load right?

Comment: yes,the user should choose once the feed and  it display the latest news everytime, and not the current news one time till the "user" chooses again the feed.

Comment: guess you need to either use **pooling** or **socket** events, pooling may be intervals you search or socket and listen for the event to be fired then you update your ui

Comment: i was hopping for some simple code change to do the magic

Comment: haha if its pooling i can assist you with that

Comment: please assist then! what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying or trying to accomplish, is to either use

- polling
- event or socket connection ([socket.io](http://socket.io))

Now with Polling, you set a particular interval to always go and check for new updates. This path is not too efficient as you might go to the server to retrieve new information and there might be none returned as at the time you sent the request.

Sample

```
var interval = 3000// milliseconds
function fetchFeeds(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        // goto the server here and manage returned record
    }, interval);
 }
```

For Events: you can check up on server side events  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) but for only HTML5, but nice stuff.

Will advise to go for socket instead, check [socket.io](http://socket.io)